# TimeOut on CodeChef

Tags: haskell

I'm new to CodeChef and thought of trying a few problems, so I solved the "Bytelandian gold coins" problem. (http://www.codechef.com/problems/COINS/) I'm getting instant results on my computer, CodeChef sets a 9 second time limit, but i'm still getting TimeOuts from CodeChef. I don't have any clue anymore what causes this. Any hints would be helpfull.

My code:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Maybe

main = do
    catch (main' M.empty 1) (const $ return ()) 

main' _ 11 = return ()
main' m c = do
    x <- readLn
    let (k,m2) = sol m x
    print k
    main' m2 (c+1)


sol :: Map Integer Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Map Integer Integer)
sol m x     |M.member x m = (fromJust $ M.lookup x m,m)
            |x > x2+x3+x4 = (x,M.insert x x m)
            |otherwise = (fullSoll, M.insert x fullSoll m4)
    where
        x2 = div x 2
        x3 = div x 3
        x4 = div x 4
        (sx2, m2) = sol m x2
        (sx3, m3) = sol m2 x3
        (sx4, m4) = sol m3 x4
        fullSoll = sx2+sx3+sx4
```

Comment: If you can live with Int keys rather than Integers, Data.IntMap may be more efficient than Data.Map.

Comment: Maybe that would help the efficiency a little bit. But I'm getting instant results already on my pc, even for the 10 highest possible testcases (and one run only consists of maximum 10 cases). So I suppose there must be some problem in my IO, but I really don't know where to look anymore.

Comment: Does CodeChef run your program on their hardware? The IO doesn't look particularly suspect in your code, and if CodeChef is doing the compiling there are enough options to upset performance. Not compiling with -O2, setting the heap too small (so more garbage collection), etc. They might run on slower machines than yours. Perhaps try to find out the compile options they use and test them on your PC.

Comment: I can't find any compile options. But I get instant results in ghci without compiling, so I don't think that should matter very much. In the list of succesfull submitions I found this one: http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/41839. And my solution is about double the speed, I really don't understand it any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sol` doesn't terminate when the `x == 0`. When `x` is 1 it is fine because all of `x2, x3, x4` are 0, and their sum is less than `x`, meaning the second guard is true, and no recursion. However, when the input is 0, then the recursive case kicks in, and it never terminates.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem. A stupid mistake from me.